# Unknown package com.strinkle.warble found in android stack trace

Tags: android, stack-trace

I am getting a lot of crashes in my app and I am having trouble locating the source. It doesn't seem to come from any libraries that I use. Also when I search Google for "com.strinkle.warble" in quotes I get zero hits. Literally 0. Any tips on how to track this down would be great.

Here is the stack trace as reported by Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager;
       at com.strinkle.warble.lqDiqe.WvKvFq(Unknown Source)
       at com.strinkle.warble.PreProcActivity.ZqNgdX(Unknown Source)
       at com.strinkle.warble.PreProcActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5976)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.tesseractmobile.solitairemulti-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/data/com.tesseractmobile.solitairemulti/app_app_apk/solitairemulti.dat.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
       at com.strinkle.warble.lqDiqe.WvKvFq(Unknown Source)
       at com.strinkle.warble.PreProcActivity.ZqNgdX(Unknown Source)
       at com.strinkle.warble.PreProcActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5976)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

**EDIT:**
To be clear I don't use LocalBroadcastManager in my code. That is the part that concerns me. I am starting to suspect that this is malicious code. Where does com.strinkle.warble come from!?!?!? It's such a strange package name. It doesn't come up on Google searches.

Comment: share your code

Comment: `Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.tesseractmobile.solitairemulti-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/data/com.tesseractmobile.solitairemulti/app_app_apk/solitairemulti.dat.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]`, that's maybe your app has many classes result to multiple dex files. Please confirm the `LocalBroadcastManager`class is in `classes.dex`

Comment: Are you enable your multi_dex in grdale.build ? This problem happens for different package name.

Comment: ur class could not be found check ur `LocalBroadcastManager`

Comment: @AslamHossin I'm not using multidex. I do use proguard though to keep the amount methods under the 56K limit.

Comment: @RajeshPanchal What code would you like to see? I don't even know where to start looking for this.

Comment: When is this happening ? I mean at what stage of your application interaction is this happening ? Make sure the libraries you are using are not using any kind of synamic code generation.